# Print leading string by default every time print() is used

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, printing

How can I make `print()` to always print a leading string every time it is used. I need it to keep track of the things that are printed to the console based on execution ID every time `print()` is used.

For example, if I have: `execution_id = "123abc"`

and I do: `print("My Name")`

I want the output in the logs to be:

```
123abc - My Name
```

Any ideas?

We thought about using the python logger, but we are looking for a solution focused on using `print()`. Maybe by modifying the print() function. So that by default everything that is printed has a leading sting.

Comment: Use a logger instead?

Comment: Use a proper logger - https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but we are focused on finding a solution for the `print()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found these two alternatives to create a modified version of the `print()` function. However, that means that the new print function is usable only within the module being executed.

1. Using decorators

```
def my_decorator(func):
    def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
        return func("123abc -", *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped_func

my_print = my_decorator(print)
my_print("My message")
```

```
Output: 123abc - My message
```

2. Using the bultins

```
import builtins
def my_print(*args):
    builtins.print("123abc -", *args)

my_print("My message")
```

```
Output: 123abc - My message
```

***Update***:
To modify the `print()` function saved in the **builtins** package to have its effects anytime and anywhere print is used (so that the modification only needs to be performed once in the whole script) you can use the code below. I found it in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13871861/21905824

```
def modify_print_builtin():
    try:
        import __builtin__ as builtins # Python 2
    except ImportError:
        import builtins # Python 3

    _print = print # keep a local copy of the original print
    builtins.print = lambda *args, **kwargs: _print("123abc -", *args, **kwargs)

modify_print_builtin()
print("My message")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the in-built logging module with a formatter.
See here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#formatter-objects

`%(funcName)s` is probably what you are looking for

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. We thought about it indeed. However, we are using the logger already for some other purpose and we specifically want to use print() for these logs.

Comment: For whoever is interested in using the `logging.Formatter` class. In this page it is explained how to use it:  In this page it is explained how to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57204920/how-to-properly-format-the-python-logging-formatter